# Gmail keeps deleting emails

Tags: gmail

I have two emails that are linkedin notifications, and they keep ending up in my trash folder.  I uncheck the Trash label and they go back into my Inbox.  A minute later they pop back into the trash.  I have gone through all my filters, and I don't see any that could be matching these emails.  How do I stop these emails from being deleted?

Comment: Are you using any Gmail add-ons, like Boomerang or Mailstrom? Are you using a desktop email client, like Thunderbird?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe add a filter to Never Mark as Spam? or even Mark as Important